# Java - How to strip an email signature while parsing the email?

Tags: java, email, outlook, email-attachments

I have a program which checks the unread email from an inbox, parses and sends the content of the email to a record. If there are any images in the email, those images will be sent as attachments to the record. Now if any email is having an image in the signature part of the email, that image is also being sent as an attachment.

Is there a way that I can check for the images in the signature part of the email and ignore them? or Is there a way around where I can skip the entire signature content from getting parsed?

Emails sent from outlook are high priority here. So Is there a particular standard in outlook of how the emails can be parsed for signatures?.

Comment: Slow down a bit.  What does your code have to do with the standards of Outlook?  You're just looking to remove images from signatures, right?

Comment: I think he's wondering if emails from Outlook have a particular format that will allow him to easily strip signature stuff (whereas maybe some other provider has a different format, which isn't as big a concern).

Comment: Yes, Actually I am looking to remove the images from the signature of all the emails that I am parsing. Is there a way that I can detect the start of the signature portion of an email while parsing the email body. Currently I am parsing the email for any images and the problem with this approach is if there are any images in the body part of the email, then those emails are also getting stripped off by my code. Any idea to resolve the problem?

Comment: When you say "If there are any images in the email", are you referring to attached images **only** or to **both** images attached to the email and those embedded within its body?

Comment: both. the images embedded in the body and the attachments as well.